# How create regex for "OR" condition <TableName>dataTable().fnFilter

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

Getting hard time to make a regex for "OR" condition work.

Example: table has 2 columns and trying to serach on 2nd column ( let's say - "status" column) and search regex is :

```
//javascript
$('#filter-status').change(function() {
     searchTxt =  "Not Shared|Private";
     <table name>.dataTable().fnFilter(searchTxt , 2,true);
}
```

Looks like it is pulling up data with "Not Shared" as status bu not pulling up data with "Private" status.

Even tried with searchTxt as "^(Not Shared)|(Private)$"  and "/(^Not Shared$)|(^Private$)/ 
"

Not sure what I am missing. Can anyone help?

Comment: What about `"(Not Shared)|(Private)"` ?

Comment: ^(Not Shared|Private)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found out it was not Regex issue. But Jquery dataTable().fnFilter smartsearch issue. I just had to make the 4th argument `false` and it worked.

```
<table name>.dataTable().fnFilter(searchTxt, 2, true, false);
```

Comment: I will upvote if you pose example will code, this will e much more helpful:)

Comment: @deckoff It's the 4th variable in the fnFilter() function, so: `<table name>.dataTable().fnFilter(searchTxt, 2, true, false);` would be how he fixed his problem http://www.datatables.net/api#fnFilter.